# After adding TTL to mongodb i cannot insert more than once golang

Tags: mongodb, go

## Context:

So i have created a ttl using an IndexModel but when i insert something into a collection i cannot isnert again and it returns this as an error: `(0xd3cc80,0xc0004385b0)`.

Changing the value of "exp" makes it possible to insert once more but after that it doesn't work anymore.

## ***Code:***

```golang
    indexOptions := options.Index().SetExpireAfterSeconds(int32(url.Expires))
    indexName, err := c.Coll.Indexes().CreateOne(
        context.TODO(),
        mongo.IndexModel{Keys: bson.M{"expires": 1}, Options: indexOptions},
    )
    if err != nil {
        println(err)
        return nil, err
    }

    println(indexName)

    _, err = c.Coll.InsertOne(c.Ctx, url)
    return url, err
```

Note that url.Expires is a Unix timestamp in the future (around +1 days from now)

Side question: When is TTL supposed to delete stuff i ran a test where i set it to 20 seconds and it still hasn't deleted it yet.

### Edit 1 | Indexes:

```
[
  { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: '_id_' },
  { v: 2, key: { exp: 1 }, name: 'exp_1', expireAfterSeconds: 20 },
  {
    v: 2,
    key: { expires: 1 },
    name: 'expires_1',
    expireAfterSeconds: 1672819674
  },
  {
    v: 2,
    key: { expires: -1 },
    name: 'expires_-1',
    expireAfterSeconds: 1672906158
  },
  {
    v: 2,
    key: { expires: 3000 },
    name: 'expires_3000',
    expireAfterSeconds: 1672906336
  },
  {
    v: 2,
    key: { created_at: 1 },
    name: 'created_at_1',
    expireAfterSeconds: 1672835415
  }
]
```

These are the indexes, the issue seems to be the fact that the keys value is always a set value e.g.: 1, -1 etc... How would i solve this is there an automatic way to increment the number for each inserted element?

### Edit 2:

the issue is that it is the same value by chaging it to take either a random number or something unique then it works but this feels way too hacky is there any better way of doing this

Comment: Check the index in the mongod server, this sounds like it was inadvertently made unique.

Comment: Your side question: TTL indexes are checked every 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the problem has nothing to do with uniqueness of the values in the documents. Indeed I don't believe the problem has anything to do with inserting data at all. Rather the issue appears to be that you are creating duplicate *indexes*.

The code you shared shows two things:

1. The function first attempts to create a new index using an expiry duration provided by one of the fields in the `url` object.
2. It *then* attempts to insert a document into the collection using the same `url` object.

There is almost no situation in which this block of code should be creating the index at all, let alone doing so while using a duration value provided in the same object that is being inserted into the database. Index creation is a maintenance type of task that is typically done infrequently on a collection, it is intended to be done via the same code that writes to the database. Moreover, the TTL index is intended to set the consistent expiry time behavior for all documents in the collection. It is the *value* of the corresponding field in the documents that controls their specific expiry.

I would suggest the following:

- Remove all code related to index creation from this function.
- Select the single index from the following four "duplicates" that correctly defines the behavior that you are looking to have and remove the other three. If none of them do, then remove all four and create the single new index that you desire.

```
  { v: 2, key: { exp: 1 }, name: 'exp_1', expireAfterSeconds: 20 },
  {
    v: 2,
    key: { expires: 1 },
    name: 'expires_1',
    expireAfterSeconds: 1672819674
  },
  {
    v: 2,
    key: { expires: -1 },
    name: 'expires_-1',
    expireAfterSeconds: 1672906158
  },
  {
    v: 2,
    key: { expires: 3000 },
    name: 'expires_3000',
    expireAfterSeconds: 1672906336
  },
```

- Double check that you want the final index listed in your question which is a separate TTL on `created_at`. If not, remove that one as well.

> These are the indexes, the issue seems to be the fact that the keys value is always a set value e.g.: 1, -1 etc... How would i solve this is there an automatic way to increment the number for each inserted element?

You are conflating two ideas here. The *definition of the index* is not the same thing as the *value of the field in the documents*. You will have *one* TTL index for this field for the collection and it will have a static definition. You will *not* be incrementing anything here. The `1` (or `-1`) [value in the index definition](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/) represents the ordering (ascending or descending). It has nothing to do with the value of the field in the documents, and it should really never be anything other than `1` or `-1` for standard indexes.

##### Open Questions

We could do a much better job of answering this question if there were more and consistent troubleshooting information provided. Some helpful clarifications would include:

- What version is the database?
- What version is the Go driver?
- In the field that you are interesting named `exp` or `expires`? You reference both field names when describing your situation and also have indexes with both.
- What is the stringified version of the error message and what line is generating it? The hex values you referenced are unhelpful for our purposes.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question but i saw it explained in some places like it was for deleting data that has a general expiration, i did not understand that is was for the entire collection rather than individual elements.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. A TTL index will delete full documents from the collection based on the value of the associated field in the document.